# ASP.NET Core 7 C# : AWS Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel ScanFilter with condition for list object column

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

How do I scan with `ScanFilter` with conditions on DynamoDB List object? Would `scanFilter.AddCondition("brandIDs", ScanOperator.Contains, brandId);` return filter for records which the `brandIDs` list contains the `brandId` string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work:

```
var scanFilter = new ScanFilter();
scanFilter.AddCondition(listColumnName, ScanOperator.Contains, listColumnValue);

var scanRequest = new ScanRequest
        {
            TableName = tableName,
            FilterExpression = scanFilter.FilterExpression,
            ExpressionAttributeValues = scanFilter.ExpressionAttributeValues
        };

var response = await client.ScanAsync(scanRequest);

return response.Items;
```

Comment: `'ScanFilter' does not contain a definition for 'FilterExpression' and no accessible extension method 'FilterExpression' accepting a first argument of type 'ScanFilter' could be found`

Comment: `'ScanFilter' does not contain a definition for 'ExpressionAttributeValues' and no accessible extension method 'ExpressionAttributeValues' accepting a first argument of type 'ScanFilter' could be found`